# Split IEnumerable by predicate

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

In order to divide an `IEnumerable` in C# by a predicate, I implemented the following (in a static class):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBeforeIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> pred)
{
    //This exists to store the predicate satisfier, which I kept as
    //the first T in the inner IEnumerable (except, maybe the first one).
    T predSatis = default(T);
    while(input.Any())
    {
        var temp = input.TakeWhile(v => !pred(v));
        //I was told that the below is the best test for default-ness.
        //(I assume that pred(default(T)) is always false.)
        if(predSatis == null || predSatis.Equals(default(T)))
            yield return temp;
        else
            yield return (new List<T>{predSatis}).Concat(temp);

        input = input.SkipWhile(v => !pred(v));
        predSatis = input.FirstOrDefault();
        input = input.Skip(1);
    }
    if(predSatis != null && !predSatis.Equals(default(T)))
        yield return new List<T>{predSatis};
}
```

This returns as follows:

- `new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5}.SplitBeforeIf(v => v % 2 == 0)` gives `{{1}, {2,3}, {4,5}}`
- `new List<int>{6,1,2,3,4,5}.SplitBeforeIf(v => v % 2 == 0)` gives `{{}, {6, 1}, {2,3}, {4, 5}}`
- `new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6}.SplitBeforeIf(v => v % 2 == 0)` gives `{{1}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6}}`.

I have 3 questions (besides any other comments on the code):

1. I see that, despite my best efforts, this is \$O(n^2)\$. Why? Can this be improved for a generic `IEnumerable`?
2. This does not support a stateful predicate or a stateful `IEnumerable` input. Can this be remedied?
3. This looks awfully like [Clojure's partition-by](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6902). How does Clojure avoid the first issue (it may also have the second, but functional programming dislikes state anyway)?

Being a little pedantic about these things, I also would prefer solutions that don't accumulate values into another data structure (just to see if full laziness is possible).

Comment: your implementation doesn't give you the results you are expecting.`1, 2, 3, 4, 5 => {1}{2,3}{4,5}` ; `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 => {}{1}{2,3}{4,5}` ; `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 => {1}{2,3}{4,5}{6}`; `2, 3, 4, 5  => {}{2,3}{4,5}`

Comment: If you fear your algoritmh is `O(N^2)` in complexity, just run it with input size doubling and see if the runtime doubles or quadruples. If it doubles it is O(n), if it quadruples it is O(n^2)

Comment: @Gareth: Yes, you're right. I'll edit that...

Comment: @Caridorc: I tested it a few times and it does seem to be n^2, I just want to understand why. (I'll edit to reflect this.)

Comment: @HemanGandhi - run through your algorithm with an input where every element satisfies the predicate -> the while loop will run *n* times with a bunch of O(n) operations inside giving you O(n^2)

Comment: Full laziness *may* be possible, but it's certainly not going to be maintainable. You would have a situation in which both the "outer" and the latest "inner" enumerators can advance the "source" enumerator, and if the outer one advances it then it needs to cache the items it advances over so that the inner one can return them later.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Additionally supporting the case where an inner enumerable is enumerated multiple times would cause problems; you'd need to memoize the inner enumerables, even if you compute them lazily, to make sure it works properly.  Of course, if the inner enumerables could be very large, or the items themselves have a large memory footprint, then just materializing the whole group may not be an option, however much it makes the code much easier.

Comment: Did you get a comparison of clojure?

Comment: @Gareth, I tried my own clojure thing and I think it lacks the first of the above pitfalls.

Answer (score 8):

So I thought I'd try this out with a test enumerable.

```
public class NumberValues : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public NumberValues(int startValue, int endValue)
    {
        _endValue = endValue;
        _startValue = startValue;
        counter = 0;
    }
    public NumberValues(int endValue) : this(0, 10) { }

    public int counter { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {

        var iterator = _startValue;
        while (iterator < _endValue)
        {
            Trace.Write(iterator + ",");
            iterator++;
            counter++;
            yield return iterator;
        }

    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

followed closely by

```
    [TestCase(0,5)]
    [TestCase(1,5)]
    [TestCase(0,6)]
    [TestCase(1,6)]
    [TestCase(0,10)]
    [TestCase(1,10)]
    public void TestSkipBeforeIf(int start, int end)
    {
        var numberValue = new NumberValues(start,end);
        numberValue.SplitBeforeIf(i => i%2 == 0).ToList();
    }
```

which results in the following output.

```
0,5 > 0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,  - 25
1,5 > 1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,  - 19
0,6 > 0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,  - 27
1,6 > 1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,  - 21
0,10 > 0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,  - 65
1,10 >     1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,  - 55

0,20 > 230
0,40 > 860
0,100 > 5150
```

But why?

```
        while (input.Any())
        {
            var temp = input.TakeWhile(v => !pred(v));
            if (predSatis == null || predSatis.Equals(default(T)))
                yield return temp;
            else
                yield return (new List<T> { predSatis }).Concat(temp);

            input = input.SkipWhile(v => !pred(v));
            predSatis = input.FirstOrDefault();
            input = input.Skip(1);
        }
```

if you evaluate your 2 lines

```
input = input.SkipWhile(v => !pred(v));
predSatis = input.FirstOrDefault();
```

over iterations of your while loop, it is necessary to expand the input variable for each iteration.

```
input.SkipWhile(pred).FirstOrDefault
input.SkipWhile(pred).SkipWhile(pred).FirstOrDefault
input.SkipWhile(pred).SkipWhile(pred).SkipWhile(pred).FirstOrDefault
input.SkipWhile(pred).SkipWhile(pred).SkipWhile(pred).SkipWhile(pred).FirstOrDefault
```

having seen this, we now consider the evaluation of input.SkipWhile(!pred)

so over 100 iterations

```
pred = x => x % 2 == 0 : 5150
pred = x => x % 3 == 0 : 3600
pred = x => x % 4 == 0 : 2625
pred = x => x % 5 == 0 : 2120
pred = x => x % 6 == 0 : 1849
pred = x => x % 15 == 0 : 837
pred = x => x % 20 == 0 : 605
pred = x => x % 25 == 0 : 504
pred = x => x % 30 == 0 : 564
pred = x => x % 30 == 0 : 413
```

Your functions behaviour is therefore dependent not just on the size of your data, but on the form of your predicate.

For your own analysis, this is what I used for evaluating the predicate

```
   [TestCase(1,5000,10)]
   public void TestSkipBeforeIf(int start, int end, int mod)
   {
        var numberValue = new NumberValues(start,end);
        numberValue.SplitBeforeIf(i => i%mod == 0).ToList();
   }
```

I'm not clear what you meant by stateful predicate or IEnumerable, however in terms of the IEnumerable I have maintained a count as state. Similarly I could maintain a count for the pred, or add some bizarre checking behaviour.

```
Func<object, int, bool> predStateful = (y,x) =>
{
    if (x == y.Check(x))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return x%mod == 0;
};
Func<int, bool> pred = x => predStateful(MyCheckingObject,x);
numberValue.SplitBeforeIf(pred).ToList();
```

Thanks for the interesting question.

**EDIT**: Modified Chunk function using a predicate. 
[original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389203/how-do-i-chunk-an-enumerable)

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TValue>> Chunk<TValue>(
                    this IEnumerable<TValue> values,
                    Func<TValue,bool> pred)
    {
        using (var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return GetChunk(enumerator, pred).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    private static IEnumerable<T> GetChunk<T>(
                     IEnumerator<T> enumerator,
                     Func<T,bool> pred)
    {
        do
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        } while (!pred(enumerator.Current) && enumerator.MoveNext());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the interesting points! I meant a similar thing by "stateful predicate" as you've seen for the "stateful `IEnumerable`" - if the predicate captures variables (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c/).

Comment: here is a function that returns lazily http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389203/how-do-i-chunk-an-enumerable

Comment: I like the idea behind that SO thread. Unfortunately, I have to use the predicate.

Comment: the predicate is easy to add, by just replacing `int size` with `Func<int,bool> pred`

Comment: I think the issue is that the chunk size is fixed and I'd like the predicate on the value type of the `IEnumerable`. Either way, I think my code turns out to be much like http://stackoverflow.com/a/23652544/5292630

Comment: I added an edit to show you what I meant. see above under  EDIT: Modified Chunk function using a predicate

Answer (score 5):

I can't really answer your questions but I can show you a simpler (easier to read) way to achieve the same result :

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBeforeIf<T> (
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var temp = new List<T> ();

    foreach (var item in source)
        if (predicate (item))
        {
            if (temp.Any ())
                yield return temp;

            temp = new List<T> { item };
        }
        else
            temp.Add (item);

     yield return temp;
}
```

### Edit

If you want something with no intermediate data structure and with O(n) complexity, I think this could do the job.

*Note that it's a bit convoluted ; I tried to make a class with a state machine like the ones used internally by Linq [WhereEnumerableIterator for example] but without success

It could be "simpler" (all state contained in one single method) with VB.Net because it has lambda Iterator*

```
static class Extensions
{
    private enum EnumerationState
    {
        Ended = -1,
        Started = 0,
        Enumerating
    }

    private static EnumerationState currentState;

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBeforeIf<T> (
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator ())
        {
            currentState = EnumerationState.Started;
            var counter = 0;

            while (currentState != EnumerationState.Ended)
            {
                ++counter;
                yield return SplitBeforeIfInternal (enumerator, predicate, counter);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> SplitBeforeIfInternal<T> (IEnumerator<T> enumerator, Func<T, bool> predicate, int amountToSkip)
    {
        while (amountToSkip > 0)
        {
            --amountToSkip;

            if (currentState == EnumerationState.Enumerating && amountToSkip == 0)
                yield return enumerator.Current;

            bool hasMoved;

            while ((hasMoved = enumerator.MoveNext ()) && !predicate (enumerator.Current))
                if (amountToSkip == 0)
                    yield return enumerator.Current;

            currentState = hasMoved ? EnumerationState.Enumerating : EnumerationState.Ended;
        }
    }
}
```

I join the VB.Net equivalent just for informatory purpose :

```vb
Module Extensions

    Private Enum EnumerationState
        Ended = -1
        Started = 0
        Enumerating
    End Enum

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Iterator Function SplitBeforeIf(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), predicate As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
        Using e = source.GetEnumerator
            Dim state = EnumerationState.Started
            Dim amountToSkip = 0

            While state <> EnumerationState.Ended
                amountToSkip += 1

                Yield Iterator Function()
                          While amountToSkip > 0
                              amountToSkip -= 1

                              If state = EnumerationState.Enumerating AndAlso amountToSkip = 0 Then Yield e.Current

                              Dim hasMoved = e.MoveNext

                              While hasMoved AndAlso Not predicate(e.Current)
                                  If amountToSkip = 0 Then Yield e.Current
                                  hasMoved = e.MoveNext
                              End While

                              state = If(hasMoved, EnumerationState.Enumerating, EnumerationState.Ended)
                      End Function()
            End While
        End Using
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: This was one of my implementations. I just wanted to force myself to use lazy sequences and IEnumerables instead of having a List. (Sorry for not mentioning that.) Technically, I think this fixes question 1 everywhere and 2 for a stateful predicate.

Comment: @HemanGandhi having a backing array (what `List` essentially is) does not prevent it from being lazy. `yield` is what makes it lazy.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanSibahi My point was that I wanted the inner lists to also be lazy.

Comment: I really like this idea. Unfortunately, it seems that unless you enumerate the previous inner values, you won't progress through the IEnumerable. (ie. SplitBeforeIf().ElementAt(n)) returns the same thing for any n.) I wonder if this can be altered?

Comment: @HemanGandhi indeed... something I neglected during tests ; I've updated the code to add a counter incremented in the "outer loop" and decremented in the "inner" one to reach the good point. Not ideal but that do the job (I think)

Comment: Kudos for `source` and `predicate` parameter names. I'd make `Func<T, bool>` a plain `Predicate<T>` delegate though.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I choose `Func` only because it's what the other "Linq" method do too ;)

Comment: Your use of brackets in that first code snippet is just evil.

Comment: @Shelby115 most of the language I use the most don't use bracket (VB.Net) and/or rely mainly on indentation to identify block (python, F#/OCaml) so I tend to use them when strictly required

Answer (score 4):

- because it is a public method you should validate the arguments at least against `null`, but according to Ben Aaronson's comment

  > You shouldn't do guard checks like this inside an iterator method because they'll only get checked when the code starts iterating, rather than when the method is called.

  you should then call a separate method where the Enumeration will take place.
- omitting braces `{}` although they might be optional can lead to serious bugs. I would like to encourage you to always use them to make your code less error prone **and** more readable.
- names like `predSatis` which needs comments like `to store the predicate satisfier` are a sign that the variables are named bad. If you have the feeling that you need a variable you should just name it well although it will involve more typing but the readability of the code increases a lot. If you had named this `predicateSatisfier` it would have been clear what it is about. That is true for `pred` parameter as well.
- <s>`if(predSatis == null || predSatis.Equals(default(T)))` well, the first check is superflous because for value types it won't do anything and for reference types `default(T)` equals to `null`. So better just use `if (predSatis.Equals(default(T)))`</s>
- Linq methods are a great way to reduce typing and a lot of devs think it is easier to read. But using 5 different linq methods to do this job of which 2 are using the same predicate is over the top IMO.

Using just a plain foreach with the support of `List<T>` will run in `O(N)`

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBeforeIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
    }

    return SafeSplitBeforeIf(input, predicate);
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SafeSplitBeforeIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return result;
            result.Clear();
        }
        result.Add(item);
    }

    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had said that I didn't want a List in order to make the inner lists lazy as well (a part of my pedantry). Also, I compared against null because I was getting some sort of null pointer exception without it.

Comment: @HemanGandhi you are right about the `null` check. I have edited my answer to address the lazyness of the inner enumerables as well.

Comment: @Heslacher You're not actually lazily computing the inner values.  You're eagerly generating all of them, you're just creating a sequence that's *super* inefficient to enumerate with all of the nested concats and by wrapping every single item in an array.  Your solution is just strictly worse than if you had used a list.

Comment: @Servy its worse than that it throws an `StackOverflowException`.  I rolled it back to the version using a `List<T>`.

Comment: @Heslacher it's always better then the `CodeOverviewException` ;-P

Comment: You shouldn't do guard checks like this inside an iterator method because they'll only get checked when the code starts iterating, rather than when the method is called. MS splits LINQ methods for this reason: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with your questions, but below you'll find another implementation which avoids instatiation of new lists. The penalty is though the lst.Count(), but if the frequence of elements satisfying the predicate is high it may be ok?

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBeforeIf2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> pred)
{
  var lst = input.TakeWhile((x, i) => i == 0 ? true : !pred(x));
  var count = lst.Count();
  if (count > 0)
  {
    yield return lst;

    foreach (var l in input.Skip(count).SplitBeforeIf2(pred))
      yield return l;
  }

}
```

As the above solution has a rather poor performance for large datasets, I went on and found the solution below which seems to be more effecient:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBeforeIf4<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> pred)
{
  int count = 0;
  IGrouping<bool, T> group = null;
  while ((group = input.Skip(count).TakeWhile((x, i) => i == 0 ? true : !pred(x)).GroupBy(x => true).FirstOrDefault()) != null)
  {
    yield return group.Select(x => x);
    count += group.Count();
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `yield return lst` come outside the if statement? Also, I love the recursion!

Comment: @HemanGandhi placing the yield return lst inside the if statement prevents the last empty selection to be returned.