# Combine neighboring parts of an array based on a condition

Tags: c#, array

I have written this code which takes a one dimensional array, for example:

`{"abc","ade","sss","fgw","asd","lka","o"}`

and turns it into an array of arrays, combining the elements which do not meet the condition.

For the condition `m=>!m.Contains("a")` for example, the output will be:

`{{"abc","ade"},{"sss"},{"fgw"},{"asd","lka"},{"o"}}`

The code works, but i suspect there is a linq way to do it, and refrain from using temporary variables that i dislike.

```
    public static string[][] combineBy(this string[] inp,Func<string,bool> f)
    {
        List<string[]> holdElements = new List<string[]>();
        while (inp.Length!=0)
        {
            if (f.Invoke(inp[0]))
            {
                holdElements.Add(new string[] { inp[0] });
                inp = inp.Skip(1).ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                var toAdd = inp.TakeWhile(n => !f.Invoke(n));
                holdElements.Add(toAdd.ToArray());
                inp = inp.Skip(toAdd.Count()).ToArray();
            }
        }
        return holdElements.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You dislike temporary variables but you yourself are using them in `var toAdd = ...` instead of `holdElements.Add(inp.TakeWhile(n => !f.Invoke(n)));` ;-P which is inefficient anyway because you first enumerate the `TakeWhile` into an array and then you `Count()` instead of `ToArray` it in the first place and use the `Length` later.

Comment: Seems hypocritical but it was meant for debugging and readability reasons, I didn't succeed in boiling down the code more than that tho.

Comment: Just as a curiosity: I think this can be implemented in terms of http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134363/split-ienumerable-by-predicate. The predicate, it seems, would be `value => !value.contains("a")`. In fact, perhaps, `combineBy(list, predicate)` is generally `SplitBeforeIf(list, val => !predicate(val))`.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to incorporate changes from answers.  It breaks the Q+A nature of the site.

Comment: I didnt incorporate changes from answers whatsoever. the code was simply not doing what i said it should because of a typo which is against the rules of this site

Comment: @forsvarir what should i do then? the question is incorrect, non working code isnt allowed

Comment: @downrep_nation Once you've started receiving answers that identify issues with your code, you shouldn't edit it.  If you realise your code is broken, or you incorporate feedback answers then the best option is to post a followup question, see http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/4203 for more info

Comment: but the code wasnt broken... the explanation to what it should do was

am i allowed to edit the explanation?

Comment: @downrep_nation You can update the explanation, but the change I rolled back inverted an if statement `if (!f.Invoke(inp[0]))` which was a code change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some general remarks about your code:

- `combineBy` use PascalCase for method names
- `f` it's not a good parameter name, if it's a condition function they are usualy named `predicate`
- `predicate.Invoke(...)` - you can call it directly with `predicate(...)`
- `values.TakeWhile(n => !predicate(n))` - do not enumerate it twice, call `ToArray` and use it in the subsequent lines
- if you like it the LINQ way you can write `values.Any()` instead of `values.Length != 0` and `values.First()` instead of `values[0]` also this `new string[] { inp[0] }` could be turned into `values.Take(1).ToArray()`
- don't use abbreviations for variables like `inp` or `f`, use full names like `values` and `predicate`

x

```
public static string[][] CombineBy(this string[] values, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    var result = new List<string[]>();
    while (values.Any())
    {
        if (predicate(values.First()))
        {
            result.Add(values.Take(1).ToArray());
            values = values.Skip(1).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            var toAdd = values.TakeWhile(n => !predicate(n)).ToArray();
            result .Add(toAdd);
            values = values.Skip(toAdd.Length).ToArray();
        }
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

---

Unfortuantely your code doesn't seem to work and returns invalid results. This should do:

```
public static List<List<string>> CombineBy(this string[] values, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    var result = new List<List<string>>();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (predicate(value))
        {
            if (!result.Any() || !predicate(result.Last().Last()))
            {
                result.Add(new List<string>());
            }
            result.Last().Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(new List<string> { value });
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

or even without loops:

```
public static List<List<string>> CombineBy3(this string[] values, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    var result = values.Aggregate(new List<List<string>>(), (current, next) =>
    {
        if (predicate(next))
        {
            if (!current.Any() || !predicate(current.Last().Last()))
            {
                current.Add(new List<string>());
            }
            current.Last().Add(next);
        }
        else
        {
            current.Add(new List<string> { next });
        }
        return current;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you're going this far you may as well make it generic.

Comment: @EBrown right `CombineBy<T>` and `string` --> `T` +  ;-)

Comment: You got it. :) Then it's much more robust and usable.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to break it to you but your code doesn't work. For the input you've given, your code returns:

> `{ {"abc"}, {"ade"}, {"sss", "fgw"}, {"asd"}, {"lka"}, {"o"} }`

Which is clearly incorrect. Your code is also needlessly complex - you should be able to do this with one iteration through the source array:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> CombineBy(this string[] input, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    if (input == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    }
    return CombineByCore(input, predicate);
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> CombineByCore(string[] input, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    var buffer = new List<string>();
    foreach (var inputString in input)
    {
        if (predicate(inputString))
        {
            buffer.Add(inputString);
        }
        else
        {
            if (buffer.Any())
            {
                yield return buffer;
                buffer = new List<string>();
            }
            yield return new List<string>() { inputString };
        }
    }
    if (buffer.Any())
    {
        yield return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: About the `null` check, see: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/61/yield-keyword/279/correctly-checking-arguments#t=20160726110301483491  I made the same mistake :-(

Comment: @Heslacher - every day is a school day! Thanks for that - will update my answer

Comment: "every day is a school day" that what I thought some days ago as well.

Comment: Didn't mean to remove the `null` check but have another method doing it and then call the method which is `yield`ing

Comment: I was being lazy :)

Comment: @RobH your solution is lazy too ;-P but I guess as far as LINQ is concerned it's a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find a "linq way" to accomplish that... However, you could use the `GroupBy` method with 2 helper variables:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> CombineBy(this IEnumerable<string> input, Func<string, bool> prediction)
{
    bool? prevPredict = null;
    int group = 0;
    return input.GroupBy(i =>
    {
        var predict = prediction(i);
        if (!predict || predict != prevPredict)
            group++;
        prevPredict = predict;
        return group;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is nice ;-]

Comment: You call a `string[]` a `list` ... well, well, well... this needs a code review :-P

Comment: Shame on me! Improved the answer ;)

Comment: you got a typo, its accomplish.

also it doesnt work because it groups variables that return true to the predicate

Comment: @downrep_nation: Ok... than it becomes even more complex (see updated answer).